# Using an IBAction to switch back to Main View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have an application which has a number of views which are navigated to via a number of custom UIButtons from my main view.  The main view is named iBMRViewController and features some welcome graphics in the form of PNG images dropped in through interface builder.  It also features 6 custom UIButtons which I have created through code using the following;

```
// This is the code which creates, and defines the properties of the 'Warning' button on the main view.
    UIButton *warningButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
    warningButton.frame = CGRectMake(225.0, 270.0, 60.0, 60.0);
    [warningButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    warningButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [warningButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *warningButtonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Warning.png"];
    UIImage *warningStretchableButtonImageNormal = [warningButtonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [warningButton setBackgroundImage:warningStretchableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *warningButtonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"];
    UIImage *warningStretchableButtonImagePressed = [warningButtonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [warningButton setBackgroundImage:warningStretchableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [warningButton addTarget:self action:@selector(warningButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:warningButton];
```

Now, this all works fine and the buttons function perfectly, obviously I also have Actions set up for them which work perfectly.  On each page I have a UINavigationBar with a UINavigationItem on set up through interface builder and set to take me back to my main view using the following code;

```
//This is the code which opens up the new view when 'Begin' button is tapped.
-(IBAction)beginHomeButtonAction:(id)sender {
    iBMRViewController *controller = [[BeginView alloc] initWithNibName:@"iBMRViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
```

This also works, however, when it takes me back to the 'iBMRViewController' it ONLY displays what was set up via the interface builder xib file (i.e. the welcome png files).  It does not display the buttons I added through code.

Can anyone give me an idea of where I have gone wrong? Would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the `beginHomeButtonAction` doesn't "take you back to the main view". It creates a new view controller, with a new view, and presents that. It's the same *kind* of controller class, but not the same *instance* of that class.

To dismiss the view, and in fact take the user back to the main view, you have to dismiss the view that you presented from the main view. How to do this depends on how you presented then, but you could try `popViewControllerAnimated` or `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`. (google is your friend)

Comment: Thank you. I will try and understand exactly what you just said lol.  Google is indeed my friend, when I can understand what he is talking about. But the jargon is all relatively new to me so sometimes difficult. I think I have an understanding of what you are saying so I will give it a try. Thank you

Comment: True. When in doubt, post the code that presents the subviews here, in your original question.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, instead of using this code in my IBAction - iBMRViewController *controller = [[BeginView alloc] initWithNibName:@"iBMRViewController" bundle:nil]; - I changed the [[BeginView alloc] to [[iBMRViewController alloc] and it works like a charm.

Comment: Still, you're building a new view, instead of going back to the previous, existing view.